# Rails: Why does simple_format add a leading newline?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an app that has a form where the user enters data into text areas. I want to display these entries, and simple_format is pretty great since it converts the user's end-of-lines into break statements for HTML -- but it's adding a disgusting newline to the front! This is causing the content of 'entry' to be one line lower than it should be (with a blank 'newline' directly above it), and it's throwing off the formatting everywhere on my webpage.

```
def display_entry(entry)
  if entry.blank?
    'n/a'
  else
    simple_format(entry)
end
```

I tried this:

```
def display_entry(entry)
  if entry.blank?
    'n/a'
  else
    entry.slice!(0) # delete disgusting newline
    simple_format(entry)
end
```

But to no avail -- this merely sliced off the first character of my content, and the disgusting newline persevered. This makes me think simple_format is arbitrarily adding a newline to text that doesn't begin with newline. Why?? And how do I kill it??

EDIT: code from view:

```
<h2 align="center"> User </h2>
<div id="left_half">
  <div class="ibox">
    <h3 align="center"> User Info</h3>

    <div class="left">
      <%= f.label :name, 'name' %>
    </div>
    <div class ="right">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'small-text-area' %>
    </div>

    ...
    ...
```

When I display name, it has the leading newline.

```
<input class="toggle-box" id="id1" type="checkbox">
<label for="id1">User</label>
<div>
  <div class="ibox_show">
    <div class="left_show">
      <%= 'name' %>
    </div>
    <div class ="right_show">
      <%= display_entry(@user.name) %>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's not wrapping entry in 
`<p>` 
tags that you need to style?

Comment: If it is adding <p> tags, how would I remove them?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format.  Here's a link to description of some things you can do, for instance use another tag instead of p.  I would suggest doing something in your css like `parent-element p {margin-top: 0}` instead of removing the p tag.  Without seeing what you are doing it seems like the p tags would make sense.  Maybe replace with a span?

Comment: The "entry" is nothing but the result of what gets entered into the form (the :properties data member here): 
      <%= f.text_area :properties %>           Also, that line is surrounded by <div>, but I don't think that matters...

Comment: Do you have a link I could see or the output html you get when you display it?

Comment: hmm. i'm not really sure how to do that....what happens is pretty simple tho: i'm trying to display text, and all that's happening is there's a newline at the top of the text, shifting everything down by 1 line, leaving a blank space on top

Comment: Are you able to post the code from the view that you are using to display this data?

Comment: Sure! Just added it to the original post

Comment: You pasted the form.  I asked for the view where you are displaying the data.

Comment: oh haha, gotcha. posted it!

Comment: you either want to add something to your css like `.right_show p {margin-top: 0; }` or you need to remove margin-top or padding-top for .right_show.  I can't give you any more help than this.

Comment: ah, tried it, but no dice. the text does display without the newline when I don't use display_entry()

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 style_format(your_Text, html_options = {style: "display: inline"})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick to get rid of an ending newline (referred to https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

```
simple_format(f.text_field, {}, wrapper_tag: "div",)
```

the curly braces ARE IMPORTANT as the 2nd parameter. do not leave them out. Simple_format defaults to "p" tag which ends up giving a trailing line break.